# How can i parse json data from pushwoosh iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, json, pushwoosh

How can i parse below data:

```
 u = "{\"userid\":\"Living123\"}";
```

I need to get Living123 as a string.

Comment: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/

Comment: What's your real issue? Understanding what mean the data? Deserializing JSON (there are plenty of examples on SO)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads) library to convert NSString to NSDictionary.
Import "SBJson.h" in your .m file and use following code

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [u JSONValue];
NSString *userId = [dictionary valueForKey:@"userid"];
```

**Edit**

Alternatively you can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert `NSString` to `NSDictionary`

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:u options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
```